# R XTS package to.minutes – Unable to create 15m and 30m time series from 5m correctly

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to use R XTS package to.minutes to create 15m and 30m time series from 5m.  I have an xts object, which is date-time followed by OHLC.  Info about xts object x is below:

head(x) shows the following:

```
                   High    Low   Open  Close Volume
```

`2010-05-03 09:00:00 106.08 105.95 106.06 106.00   1055
2010-05-03 09:05:00 106.03 105.75 106.00 105.77   4369
2010-05-03 09:10:00 105.77 105.59 105.77 105.68   4125
2010-05-03 09:15:00 105.84 105.66 105.69 105.80   2457
2010-05-03 09:20:00 105.89 105.71 105.80 105.83   1788
2010-05-03 09:25:00 105.89 105.78 105.84 105.78    977`

str(x) shows the following:

```
> str(x)
```

`‘zoo’ series from 2010-05-03 09:00:00 to 2013-06-10 14:30:00
  Data: num [1:222473, 1:5] 106 106 106 106 106 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "High" "Low" "Open" "Close" ...
  Index:  POSIXct[1:222473], format: "2010-05-03 09:00:00" "2010-05-03 09:05:00" "2010-05-03 09:10:00" ...`

str(head(index(x))) shows the following:

```
head(str(index(x)))
```

`POSIXct[1:222473], format: "2010-05-03 09:00:00" "2010-05-03 09:05:00" "2010-05-03 09:10:00" ...
NULL`

When I convert the time series to 15m, the series starts at 09:10:00 followed by 15 minutes increments instead of starting at 09:15:00 followed by 15 minutes increments

```
> head(to.minutes(x, k=15))

                  x.Open x.High  x.Low x.Close x.Volume
```

`2010-05-03 09:10:00 106.08 105.95 105.77  105.68     9549
2010-05-03 09:25:00 105.84 105.78 105.69  105.78     5222
2010-05-03 09:40:00 105.80 105.92 105.62  106.12     9727
2010-05-03 09:55:00 106.17 106.00 106.01  106.22     6320
2010-05-03 10:10:00 106.26 106.07 106.15  106.14     8422
2010-05-03 10:25:00 106.57 106.38 106.15  106.37    10422`

The same issue when I convert the time series to 30m, the series starts at 09:25:00 followed by 30 minutes increments instead of starting at 09:30:00 followed by 30 minutes increments

```
> head(to.minutes(x, k=30))
                  x.Open x.High  x.Low x.Close x.Volume
```

`2010-05-03 09:25:00 106.08 105.95 105.69  105.78    14771
2010-05-03 09:55:00 105.80 106.00 105.62  106.22    16047
2010-05-03 10:25:00 106.26 106.38 106.15  106.37    18844
2010-05-03 10:55:00 106.37 106.27 106.01  106.00    17193
2010-05-03 11:25:00 106.04 106.20 105.95  106.29     9075
2010-05-03 11:55:00 106.34 106.35 106.24  106.39     8517`

I also tried the same using 1 minute data and had the same issue. Any thought on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty clearly described on the `?to.minutes` help page. The default is for the groups to start at the end of your data and work backwards so it doesn't necessarily pay attention to what the first value is. However, you can explicity set the `indexAt=` parameter to `"startof"`. For example

```
x <- zoo(runif(25), order.by=seq(as.POSIXct("2010-05-03 09:00:00"), 
    as.POSIXct("2010-05-03 11:00:00"), by="5 min"))

to.minutes15(x)

#                         x.Open    x.High      x.Low    x.Close
# 2010-05-03 09:10:00 0.35570172 0.3557017 0.04524480 0.04524480
# 2010-05-03 09:25:00 0.78939084 0.7893908 0.44032175 0.44032175
# 2010-05-03 09:40:00 0.05272398 0.5381755 0.05272398 0.53817548
# 2010-05-03 09:55:00 0.02198503 0.1113298 0.02198503 0.11132980
# 2010-05-03 10:10:00 0.78785210 0.8804505 0.04152860 0.04152860
# 2010-05-03 10:25:00 0.79317091 0.9497044 0.54751546 0.94970444
# 2010-05-03 10:40:00 0.03886176 0.7425681 0.03886176 0.06614893
# 2010-05-03 10:55:00 0.58684500 0.5868450 0.02794687 0.14291696
# 2010-05-03 11:00:00 0.11713868 0.1171387 0.11713868 0.11713868
```

versus

```
to.minutes15(x, indexAt="startof")

#                         x.Open    x.High      x.Low    x.Close
# 2010-05-03 09:00:00 0.35570172 0.3557017 0.04524480 0.04524480
# 2010-05-03 09:15:00 0.78939084 0.7893908 0.44032175 0.44032175
# 2010-05-03 09:30:00 0.05272398 0.5381755 0.05272398 0.53817548
# 2010-05-03 09:45:00 0.02198503 0.1113298 0.02198503 0.11132980
# 2010-05-03 10:00:00 0.78785210 0.8804505 0.04152860 0.04152860
# 2010-05-03 10:15:00 0.79317091 0.9497044 0.54751546 0.94970444
# 2010-05-03 10:30:00 0.03886176 0.7425681 0.03886176 0.06614893
# 2010-05-03 10:45:00 0.58684500 0.5868450 0.02794687 0.14291696
# 2010-05-03 11:00:00 0.11713868 0.1171387 0.11713868 0.11713868
```